# Traceback (most recent call last): File "newdata.py", line 51, in <module> temp_res.update(i['statistics']) KeyError: 'statistics'

Tags: python, api

```
search_response = youtube.search().list(q=options.q, type='video',
        part='id,snippet', maxResults=options.max_results).execute()

videos = {}

# Add each result to the appropriate list, and then display the lists of
# matching videos.
# Filter out channels, and playlists.

for search_result in search_response.get('items', []):
    if search_result['id']['kind'] == 'youtube#video':

 # videos.append("%s" % (search_result["id"]["videoId"]))

        videos[search_result['id']['videoId']] = search_result['snippet'
                ]['title']

# print "Videos:\n", "\n".join(videos), "\n"

s = ','.join(videos.keys())

videos_list_response = youtube.videos().list(id=s,
        part='id,statistics,snippet').execute()

res = []
for i in videos_list_response['items']:
    tempres = dict(v_id=i['id'], v_title=videos[i['id']])
    tempres.update(i['snippet'])
    tempres.update(i['statistics'])
    res.append(tempres)
```

Please enter the search term for videos: football
Your search term is:  football
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "data_pull.py", line 61, in 
    tempres.update(i['statistics'])
KeyError: 'statistics'

Need help to solve this error. got this code from https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2014/09/mining-youtube-python-social-media-analysis/#comment-126365 and not able to solve this error.
this file ran before error free, but after 4-5 days this error has popped up without changing the code.

Its weird but help would be appreciated!
Thanks

Comment: Post code fragment with error here

Comment: @kvorobiev Hi, I have added the code. please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Because with some videos, you cannot get its `statistics`.

Try with Search term = **Lac Troi Son Tung MTP** and you will find out [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Em0-1SkWd8E) does not have `statistics` attribute.

Comment: But this code did run almost 10-20 times before. and when i tried to run the code today, I wasnt able to do so. :(

Comment: Maybe you can try upgrading the plan of your API

Comment: Thanks! actually Google had disabled the statistics of their youtube videos, hence this problem. it got solved now!